# How to support a laravel route with "?" in url instead of "/"?

Tags: laravel

I have the following form tag :

```
< form action="../resume?jobs={{$jobs->job_id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
//remaining of the code
```

The question is how to support this route in web.php?

I tried below but not working :

```
Route::post('/resume/{?jobs}', function ($jobs) {
......
}
```

As you notice I want the url to have parameters and not backslash at the end, example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/resume?jobs=1211

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to cater for query string parameters in your routes, they will be available to you in the `Request` object.

```php
// route for /resume?jobs=123
Route::get('/resume', function (Request $request) {
    $job_id = $request->query('jobs'); // 123
})->name('resume');
```

Then in your view, all you need to do is call the `route` helper.

```php
<form action="{{ route('resume', ['jobs' => $jobs->job_id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The first parameter of `route` is the `name` of the route, from the `routes/web.php` file.
The second parameter is all your variables. If the URI doesn't have any parameters, then they will automatically be appended as a query string.

Comment: Yes guys that works perfectly! thanks for help. Even though I read and watch many videos but still sometimes confused on what $request holds other than user input texts in a form.